# EF AddOrUpdate not updating foreign key objects

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity **Holding** which has a reference to another entity **Instrument**:

```
    public class Holding
    {
        public virtual Instrument Instrument { get; set; }
    }
```

I configure the relationship using EF 6.1.3 as follows. Instrument has no reference/navigation property to Holding:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Holding>().Property(h => h.Code).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Holding>().Property(h => h.MarketValue).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Holding>().HasRequired(h => h.Instrument);
```

I'm having an issue where `context.Holdings.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Code, holding);` does not update the instrument on the holding record. If I change a different property, like MarketValue, MarketValue is updated, never Instrument though. If I add a holding, the Instrument is referenced correctly. It's just the update that isn't working as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you provide more context to the question, because `AddOrUpdate` is not a "normal" EF method, but extension method defined in `DbSetMigrationsExtensions` and is intended for very simplistic usage scenarios during database seeding. And does not handle navigation properties at all. Looks like you are trying to use it in disconnected entity scenario (?), in which case apparently it cannot be used. So if you are seeking for specific problem solution not based on `AddOrUpdate`, you need to provide the usage scenario ([mcve]).

Comment: If you don't want your bounty to go down the drain I'd quickly follow op on what Ivan suggested. At the very least we need to see the code in which the `AddOrUpdate` is carried out. Don't think that a bounty magically makes a question answerable.